# Trying to make multiple url requests in python, but response only contains one

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm trying to write a Python script that will retrieve 18 sets of JSON data and write them to a single file that I can use for a D3 project. I've only been teaching myself Python for a week, so I'm sure I'm messing this up in some simple way. I would really appreciate help finding my mistakes. Here's the script so far.

```
# Import libraries.
import requests
import json

hucs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18];
for huc in hucs:
# create request as json, dynamically altering the url to retrieve one HUC at a time.
    if(huc < 10):
        data = requests.get('http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&huc=0{}&startDT=2015-05-22&endDT=2015-05-22&parameterCd=00060&siteType=OC,OC-CO,ES,LK,ST,ST-CA,ST-DCH,ST-TS'.format(huc), stream=True).json()  
    else:
        data = requests.get('http://waterservices.usgs.gov/nwis/iv/?format=json&indent=on&huc={}&startDT=2015-05-22&endDT=2015-05-22&parameterCd=00060&siteType=OC,OC-CO,ES,LK,ST,ST-CA,ST-DCH,ST-TS'.format(huc), stream=True).json()

    # access timeSeries
    time_series = data['value']['timeSeries']

    # using open, create a file called data.json which we'll refer to as "output" in the code below
    with open('data/data.json', 'wb') as output:
        # create a single root element.
        root = bytes('{"time_series": {', 'UTF-8')
    # create counter. this is used to add the 'root' element during the first write, and to get rid of an extra comma after latitude in the final iteration.
        counter = 0
    # for every object in the time series
        for number in time_series:
            counter+=1
    # if the site has recorded values
            if(len(number['values'][0]['value']) > 0): 
    # pull out the data we want
                json_data = bytes('"site": { "properties": { "usgs_name": ' + '"' + number['name'] + '",' + \
                '"site_name": ' + '"' + number['sourceInfo']['siteName'] + '",' + \
                '"huc": "{}"'.format(number['sourceInfo']['siteCode'][0]['value']) + ',' + \
                '"streamflow": ' + '"' + number['values'][0]['value'][0]['value'] + '",' + \
                '"dateTime": ' + '"' + number['values'][0]['value'][0]['dateTime'] + '",' + \
                '"longitude": "{}"'.format(number['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['longitude']) + ',', 'UTF-8')

                if counter < len(time_series) :
                    json_data = json_data + bytes('"latitude": "{}"'.format(number['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['latitude']) + '}},', 'UTF-8')
                else:
                    json_data = json_data + bytes('"latitude": "{}"'.format(number['sourceInfo']['geoLocation']['geogLocation']['latitude']) + '}}', 'UTF-8')
    # if it's the first iteration, prepend the 'root' of the json heirarchy     
                if(counter==1):
                    output.write(root + json_data)
                else:
                    output.write(json_data)
    # close the json object             
        output.write(bytes('}}', 'UTF-8'))
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with the code? If yes, please add it to your question. Otherwise if you need general code review, there is another site for that.

Answer (score 0):

See the code `with open('data/data.json', 'wb')`  which means for every request, you open the file and delete all existed content and write the response.

The correct way to do this is `with open('data/data.json', 'ab')` when you will append the response to the existed file not delete it.

Comment: No, the mode `wb+` will still [truncate the file](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) (overwrite it). Append mode is `a`.